# Issues with Mobile Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Edit #1: After I give my height a definition of 89px, my mobile menu seems to go behind my content.

[image]

I'm having an issue with the mobile version of my navbar.  The navbar isn't as tall as logo, so when I click on it my "Home" menu item isn't being shown unless I hover over it.

Here's the pictures for both issues:

[image]

[image]

Here's my HTML:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="navbar-header">
         <a class="navbar-brand " style="margin-top: -15px; float: left;" href="#">
           <img alt="Brand" class="pull-left" style="margin-left: -15px;" src="Images/logo-resized.png">
         </a>
         <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
       </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Phone</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Android TV</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Shaw Direct</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div> 
    </div> 
  </div>
</nav>
```

And here's my CSS:

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #00AEFE;
}    
.nav.navbar-nav li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.col-xs-0 {
  display: none;
}
nav {
  height: 89px;
}
```

Comment: the css you gave is not showing any issue. it is not enough. Add full css

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @kittyCat At the moment, that is my only CSS.

Comment: @ManuelObregozo I'm trying to make my navbar height (the blue part) as tall as my logo.

Comment: This is a mobile-only issue.

Comment: @ThomasHutton Is this live somewhere we can see? Issues like these are easiest to solve via developer tools inspection.

Comment: You will have to set a height to the navbar, if your are using bootstrap or some other css framework that classes may have other properties.

Comment: @ManuelObregozo When I do that, another issue arises.  Please check my image.

Comment: if you could create a plunkr or something it will be easier to solve the issue.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/EjoTv1ZGkwdVesOetFJ1?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/XCNFbBahPaPQeRhPBYJe?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap `navbar-brand` has some padding, also the `height` of `<img>` should be controlled by additional CSS like `navbar-brand img {height:40px}`.

Although if we could see your live HTML, it would be nice.

**EDITED**

use this CSS to give some height longer than the height of your image like 100px or higher

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-header {
     height: 100px;
  }
}
```

**OR**
If you don't want to change the height of `navbar-header` you can add some padding to `navbar-toggle` button so it will add the height of `navbar-header`:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  .navbar-toggle {
     padding: 33px 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: there is no logo picture in this example beacuse it has localy addressed. so tell me how much is height of your logo picture? if it is longer than `50px` then you should minimise it to around `40px`

Comment: It's a 300x89 picture.

Comment: and does it have to be same size in your site?

Comment: Yes, it does have the same size.

Comment: Please check the **Edited** answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="navbar-brand " style="margin-top: -15px; float: left;height:auto" href="#">
            <img alt="Brand" class="pull-left" style="margin-left: -15px;" src="Images/logo-resized.png">
</a>
```

Change the height of navbar-brand class

OR

```
   <style>
   .navbar-brand img {
     max-height: 40px;
     width: auto;
    }

   </style>
```

Comment: But wouldn't that just make the image smaller, and distorted?

Comment: you can set max-height  css of image and width auto